# Ubuntu Stuck on llvmpipe Graphics

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia

I have a hybrid GPU laptop (its an [HP Pavilion Gaming](https://www.amazon.in/HP-Pavilion-i5-9300H-Graphics-15-dk0269tx/dp/B08LBK8DXJ?th=1) with Intel CPU) which I dual booted with Ubuntu-20.04 that has the following GPUs:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)`

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)`

TL;DR,The timeline is:

Installed nvidia-driver-460.

Decided to install prime-select and prime-indicator using [1].

Toggled to Intel, it asked to reboot.

Reboot froze, closed and rebooted again and it worked?
PC drained of battery, so charged and opened Ubuntu but it freezes every time.

Tried [2] to at least start but didn't update grub because I assumed I could just do that every time but updating drivers might not require that every time-thing.

Tried updating drivers but it didn't allow, rebooted anyways and can not do the thing mentioned in [2].

Went into recovery mode to prime-select NVIDIA, it shows graphics as llvmpipe, there is no way to adjust brightness, maybe for a proper reason.

I decided that I will use the prime-select thing in my PC (I'm sorry I don't remember what it was but here [[1]] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nGbWE-pvIE) is the video I used to do it, it was not prime but prime plus for me).

Now when I switched to Intel using it, it froze on boot.

So then I made some changes in the grub using this[[2]](https://youtu.be/Tg4fWsFPzSE) video.

I didn't update the grub after it booted since I assumed that if it comes again I have to edit through the grub again.

My main focus was to update the drivers or at least attempt to do so.

Right now I'm using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-460(proprietary).

It shows a 470 one (proprietary, tested) but it won't install that when I attempt to.

So now I'm stuck at the llvmpipe Graphics and whatever I try (`prime-select Intel or just trying to fix the immediate issue which is screen very dimly lit although I restarted it for only prime select and nothing else) the restart still freezes.

I have to go to recovery mode and prime-select whatever GPU was not selected, then boot to find graphics still being llvmpipe.

My issue is that I want to run in Intel GPU and would happily disable NVIDIA forever if need be.

I just want to have proper battery life while also be able to code in properly lit screen.

An important thing to note is that when I did the hybrid GPU thing from the video linked first, I also did install the graphical support to switch between GPUs i.e. prime indicator.

I switched to Intel using that, rebooted, and it froze. Then, I just rebooted again and it just worked.

If I missed any detail please request that and I'll try to update. I'm not very experienced in Ubuntu and I suspect having hybrid GPUs is the root of it all.

Edit: I also updated the grub with a `nomodeset` amend and rebooted it, but still have to go to recovery mode to do a switch after which it boots *only*

Answer (score 0):

Okay so when I boot using recovery mode, i need to reboot again instead of logging in. It literally says there how some drivers may not settle in unless the system is rebooted. I did reboot(although i have booted to windows and back to ubuntu several times but maybe it needs an immediate reboot) and it booted properly!

I think I have an okayish research done in this issue. I would love to help anyone facing a similar problem, knowing how it made me go crazy.